# Trying to hide bootstrap modal if checkbox is checked using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

So I am building a hybrid app and it is using a bootstrap modal for 'terms and conditions' and i have a checkbox to prompt the user to confirm they have read and agreed to the conditions. My code currently: loads the modal on page load, allows the checkbox to be checked, allows the modal to be closed, it then allows the user to interact with the page, you can advance on and come back to the page with the modal on, it then loads again but this time the checkbox remains checked which indicates that the cookie is storing in the session correctly but I would like the JavaScript to check if the checkbox is checked and if that returns true then hide the modal, the user doesn't need to read it again and again if they have already agreed. this is my current code:

```
function ModalShow(){
// When the user checks the checkbox...
localStorage.setItem('checkbox', 'true');

// When a user visits the page...
var checkbox = localStorage.getItem('checkbox');
    if ('checkbox'.checked == 'true') {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide')
    } else {
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
    }

}

// html
    <div class="modal-footer">
                  <p>usual terms and conditions acceptance blah.</p><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="agreement" required>
                  <input type="submit" class="modal-button btn" data-dismiss="modal" value="Submit">
                </div>
              </div>
```

Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

This line looks faulty

> if ('checkbox'.checked == 'true') {

You probably need to write this line like

```
if(checkbox === 'true') {
```

Since `checkbox` is the value returned from localstorage. In your code, `'checkbx'.checkbox` just means that you are accessing a `checkbox` property of your string 'checkbox' which is not what is intended. (*there is no .checkbox property on a String object anyway*).

Comment: unfortunately this hasn't improved the situation, it didn't break it it just achieved the same outcome.Thank you for getting back to me with an idea